# ios semaphore wait doesn't wait

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I'm having a problem using the dispatch_semaphore_wait(..) when the semaphore was created with a value greater than 0

```
sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(2);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //signals here
});

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(sema);
```

Shouldn't the wait has to wait for two signals?
In the code above it doesn't wait at all and so the release is called and the result is a crash!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not how it works.  The thread will block on the third wait, until one of the previous two are signaled.  It is a system to specify how many threads can access a resource at once.  More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24).

If you want to wait in the way you describe, you could use the [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Use a dispatch group instead of a semaphore to get this behavior.

Initialize the group to size 2 by calling `dispatch_group_enter()` twice before you start your task, and `dispatch_group_wait()` will wait for two calls to `dispatch_group_leave()` before it returns.